# Security of files in android

Tags: android

We are trying to create an app which will download eBook from server and store it locally on sdcard. We tried to DRM eBooks, after we download an eBook the DRM will take care of the security of the eBook. But later due to some reasons we left the DRM concept. Now I want to know whether we can store the eBook securely in the sdcard. The user cannot do any operations in the file other than viewing. Can we store the file in some other location where the user cannot view the file at all. In iOS we can download the file inside the Bundle itself, but for android???. We tried storing the pdf as a BLOB file in DB and tried to read it from there, in that case also we need to write the file and then read it. I am really confused on this Issue, can someone suggest me a good approach on how to proceed further. Any help would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files stored on the external storage are easy to read by other applications or from user's PC. You might need to encrypt your files if you don't want anybody else to get access. Well encrypted files can be places anywhere in the system without any risks of being read.

Storing files on the internal storage in your case does not sound good, because there are still too many devices out there with the limited amount of internal storage, where every megabyte counts.

Comment: "Well encrypted files can be places anywhere in the system without any risks of being read" -- this is called DRM, and DRM algorithms fall into two buckets: those that have been cracked, and those that nobody has bothered trying to crack just yet. In your scenario, the encryption key and algorithm will be in the app, and a simple decompile of the app would allow an attacker to decrypt the file. At most, this sort of encryption is a speed bump.

Comment: @user1427961 I'd recommend a good book on the subject: "Application Security for the Android Platform", it has more to say about security and encryption than I could do in 500 characters or less in this comment. Amazon: http://www.amazon.com/Application-Security-Android-Platform-Permissions/dp/1449315070 or search on the internet. Basically, I'd use an asymmetrical encryption, where your app sends some ID to the server and gets a book that can be decrypted on this device only. And if some books get copied, you may always easily find the responsible user from his ID used for encryption.

Comment: I'd second @scottylab's recommendation of IOCipher.  But I'm also biased, since I'm one of the developers of it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I've avoid the SDcard given it's pretty much open to all apps, as @commonsWare mentions having it internal storage offers the Android app sandbox security.

Have you considered [IOCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/iocipher/) from the excellent guys at the [guardian project](https://guardianproject.info/) it's build on SQLCipher and it allow you to create a encrypted virtual disk. The part I love about it is that it's a clone of the java.io libraries so you should only have minimal code changes.

Comment: We're happy to answer direct questions on using IOCipher, email us at support@guardianproject.info. Also, we'd love to hear about any apps that you are using IOCipher in!

Answer (score 1):

> Can we store the file in some other location where the user cannot view the file at all.

Not on external storage. You can put the book on internal storage, in which case only rooted device users would have access to it outside of your app.

Comment: thanks...can u share some code on how to store file on internal storage

Answer (score 1):

i) keep the files encrypted which are important to you.

ii) decrypt the files and move to the internal storage during runtime.

iii) Access your files only from internal storage.

Following these things will keep your file and method calling safe as they are accessible only to internal storage.
Example:(access moved assets files from internal storage )
file:///android_asset/ => file:///data/data/com.test.exmple/files/"

You can also try tools like [quixxi](http://quixxi.com) that do this for you transparently.